# how to sort an array by changing key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```php
<?php

$a=array("b", "c", "a");
asort($a);
print_r($a);

?>
```

In the above code, the output is:

```php
Array
(                                                                                     
    [2] => a
    [0] => b
    [1] => c
)
```

But I want the output to be like this:

```php
0 => a, 01 => b, 02 => c
```

Once I have the output as above, I also want to sort it by key. How can I get there?

Comment: What is sort based on?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual [`asort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)...

> asort — Sort an array and maintain index association

so you are asking it to retain the indexes.

If you don't want to retain the indexes and reset them, just use a normal `sort()`...

```
$a=array("b", "c", "a");
sort($a);
print_r($a);
```

which gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```